# C++ template: providing member-owner class to member automatically

Tags: templates, visual-c++

I'm writing my 'property' class to get rid of set and get hells from my code.
I succeeded almost successfuly, but I want to provide the 'owner class' to the class's members.

currently i should use property like this:

```
class PropertyUser
{
private:
PROPERTY_PROVIDE(PropertyUser);
                 ^^ I should provide the current class manually here.
public:
PROPERTY_DECLARE(~);
};
```

I tried a lot last one is this:

```
template<typename T>
struct OwnerClassTrait
{ };

template<typename T, class C>
struct OwnerClassTrait<T C::*>
{
    typedef C Class;
};

#define PROVIDE_CURRENT_CLASS() \
    void __Dummy_Func__(){ }; \
    typedef OwnerClassTrait<decltype(&__Dummy_Func__)>::Class CurrentClassType

#define SOME_FUNCTION(Name) \
    SomeOtherMember<CurrentClassType> Name

class Foo
{
public:
    PROVIDE_CURRENT_CLASS();
    SOME_FUNCTION(ThisTypeAutomaticallyDetectsCurrentClassType);
};
```

It gives me errors: error C2039: 'Class' : is not a member of 'OwnerClassTrait'
I think it means decltype is wrongly(removing the current scope class C::) providing the type to OwnerClassTrait.

Note that I now am using vs2012.
Did I some wrong?
Or there's an alternative way to solve this well?

Comment: Using #defines that way is fugly. MFC era is over

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will consider how to beautify and ease this more.